# uWSGI app can't find mount point, but loads html

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

uWSGI loads home.html, but doesn't start app. See error message below.

I've tried:

- Following this guide: https://vladikk.com/2013/09/12/serving-flask-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/
- Quickstart guide: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#deploying-flask
- Ran only the Flask app by running `running python sousVideRestServer.py`. This loads the app so I'm sure the Flask app is OK.

I'm not using venv.

wsgi ini file:

```
[uwsgi]

#Define uwsgi settings
master = true
processes = 5

#Must define number of threads if app is threaded
threads = 4

#Change directory
chdir = /home/pi/Projects/sousVide/

#Flask file to run
wsgi-file = sousVideRestServer.py

#Most likely app
callable = app

#socket file's location - Can be any file
socket = /home/pi/Projects/sousVide/sousVideSock.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket = 666

#Clean up
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true

#Log
#logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log

#Start stats server
stats = 192.168.1.101:1717
```

[Gist Link to complete Flask App](https://gist.github.com/aguileraGit/e9bc0ea4658e86654b11be813ca62485)
General Flask app below.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, abort, make_response, render_template
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

class RESTAnovaController(AnovaController):
    TIMEOUT_HEARTBEAT = 20

    def __init__(self, mac_address, connect=True, logger=None):
        self.last_command_at = datetime.datetime.now()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def timeout_atnot_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Not found.'}), 404)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def displayWebPage():
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        # Setup logging
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
        handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        app.logger.addHandler(handler)

        app.anova_controller = RESTAnovaController(ANOVA_MAC_ADDRESS, logger=app.logger)
        print(app.anova_controller.read_temp())

        app.run(host='192.168.1.101', port=5000, debug=False)


    except BaseException as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        app.anova_controller.close()
```

Error: WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running under `uwsgi`, the

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

condition won't be `True`, so the code under that won't run. Given what you've written, I'm fairly certain that explains your predicament.